# Where are my GTK 3 examples?

Tags: gnome, software-installation, themes, gtk, templates

I want to create a new GTK theme, so I installed `gtk-3-examples` so that I could get some template and example files, however now that I have installed it, I have no idea of where the example files are actually stored, anyone know? And is this the right package for examples? Or have I installed the wrong thing? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04.

Comment: `dpkg -L package_name` shows a list of all files and directories a package uses. This works here too: `dpkg -L gtk-3-examples`. It's a pretty long list of 227 files/folders on my system. It also recursively lists all parent folders, e.g. if something got installed to `/usr/share/doc`, it will also show `/usr/share` and `/usr`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the answer you are looking for can be found [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/bionic/amd64/gtk-3-examples/filelist).

That link shows all the files and locations after they are installed.

Also, after the `gtk-3-examples` are installed, you can access the demo by typing in

```
gtk3-demo
```

[image]

Other nice tools are

```
gtk3-icon-browser
```

[image]

and

```
gtk3-widget-factory
```

[image]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

### File list of package gtk-3-examples in bionic of architecture amd64

from https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/bionic/amd64/gtk-3-examples/filelist

```
/usr/bin/gtk-encode-symbolic-svg
/usr/bin/gtk3-demo
/usr/bin/gtk3-demo-application
/usr/bin/gtk3-icon-browser
/usr/bin/gtk3-widget-factory
/usr/share/applications/gtk3-demo.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gtk3-icon-browser.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gtk3-widget-factory.desktop
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/copyright
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/README
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/action-namespace.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application1/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application1/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application1/README
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application1/exampleapp.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application1/exampleapp.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application1/exampleappwin.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application1/exampleappwin.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application1/main.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/app-menu.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/exampleapp.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/exampleapp.gresource.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/exampleapp.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/exampleappprefs.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/exampleappprefs.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/exampleappwin.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/exampleappwin.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/gears-menu.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/main.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/org.gtk.exampleapp.gschema.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/prefs.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/resources.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application10/window.ui.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application2/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application2/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application2/exampleapp.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application2/exampleapp.gresource.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application2/exampleapp.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application2/exampleappwin.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application2/exampleappwin.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application2/main.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application2/resources.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application2/window.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application3/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application3/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application3/exampleapp.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application3/exampleapp.gresource.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application3/exampleapp.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application3/exampleappwin.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application3/exampleappwin.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application3/main.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application3/resources.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application3/window.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application4/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application4/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application4/app-menu.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application4/exampleapp.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application4/exampleapp.gresource.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application4/exampleapp.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application4/exampleappwin.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application4/exampleappwin.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application4/main.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application4/resources.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application4/window.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/app-menu.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/exampleapp.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/exampleapp.gresource.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/exampleapp.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/exampleappwin.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/exampleappwin.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/main.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/org.gtk.exampleapp.gschema.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/resources.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application5/window.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/app-menu.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/exampleapp.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/exampleapp.gresource.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/exampleapp.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/exampleappprefs.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/exampleappprefs.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/exampleappwin.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/exampleappwin.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/main.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/org.gtk.exampleapp.gschema.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/prefs.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/resources.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application6/window.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/app-menu.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/exampleapp.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/exampleapp.gresource.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/exampleapp.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/exampleappprefs.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/exampleappprefs.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/exampleappwin.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/exampleappwin.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/main.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/org.gtk.exampleapp.gschema.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/prefs.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/resources.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application7/window.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/app-menu.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/exampleapp.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/exampleapp.gresource.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/exampleapp.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/exampleappprefs.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/exampleappprefs.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/exampleappwin.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/exampleappwin.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/gears-menu.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/main.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/org.gtk.exampleapp.gschema.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/prefs.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/resources.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application8/window.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/app-menu.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/exampleapp.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/exampleapp.gresource.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/exampleapp.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/exampleappprefs.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/exampleappprefs.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/exampleappwin.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/exampleappwin.h
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/gears-menu.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/main.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/org.gtk.exampleapp.gschema.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/prefs.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/resources.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/application9/window.ui.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/bp/Makefile.am
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/bp/Makefile.in.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/bp/bloatpad.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/bp/bloatpad.gresources.xml
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/bp/gtk/help-overlay.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/bp/gtk/menus.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/builder.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/builder.ui
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/drawing.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/grid-packing.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/hello-world.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/listbox-dnd.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/plugman.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/search-bar.c
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/sunny.c.gz
/usr/share/doc/gtk-3-examples/examples/window-default.c
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Demo.gschema.xml
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.exampleapp.gschema.xml
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/gtk3-demo-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/gtk3-demo.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/gtk3-widget-factory-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/gtk3-widget-factory.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/gtk3-demo-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/gtk3-demo.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/gtk3-widget-factory-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/gtk3-widget-factory.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/gtk3-demo-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/gtk3-demo.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/gtk3-widget-factory-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/gtk3-widget-factory.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/gtk3-demo-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/gtk3-demo.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/gtk3-widget-factory-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/gtk3-widget-factory.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/gtk3-demo-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/gtk3-demo.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/gtk3-widget-factory-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/gtk3-widget-factory.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/gtk3-demo-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/gtk3-demo.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/gtk3-widget-factory-symbolic.symbolic.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/gtk3-widget-factory.png
/usr/share/man/man1/gtk-encode-symbolic-svg.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gtk3-demo-application.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gtk3-demo.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gtk3-icon-browser.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gtk3-widget-factory.1.gz
```