# Installed icons not showing up in gtk3-icon-browser

Tags: icons, gtk3, gnome-shell-extension

I have multiple icon themes installed in Ubuntu 18.04 and I am currently using a Papirus theme. I am now tinkering with a tool to create GNOME shell extensions ([Argos](https://github.com/p-e-w/argos#argos)) and wanted to use a Papirus icon for one of my list items. So, I found the gtk3-icon-browser thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695796/view-list-of-all-available-unique-icons-with-their-names-and-thumbnail/695958) and thought it seemed perfect for what I needed. But when running the gtk3-icon-browser I can only see a small set of standard icons, presumably the standard GTK icons. None of my installed icon themes show up, not even the one I am currently using.

Have I misunderstood what gtk3-icon-browser is supposed to do? Or am I missing something else?

I just want to be able to use my Papirus icons with the [Argos iconName field](https://github.com/p-e-w/argos#display). Placing the full path to an icon there does not work. So I probably need some sort of unique name and thought that the gtk3-icon-browser would provide me with that.

So I need a way to find the unique names for my icons, a way to see them in gtk3-icon-browser or a way to use my icons with Argos without the unique name. Any help on this will be very much appreciated.

Comment: GTK3 Icon Browser are only showing the Gnome Icons. Ubuntu Unity and other Applications have their own icons which are not being displayed.