# How do I find out what this strange icon in my system tray is? (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, icons, system-tray

A mysterious icon has just shown up in my system tray, a white exclamation mark within a red star:

[image: my system tray with a mysterious icon]

Nothing happens when clicked or right clicked (including no orange bar underneath like other icons here).

How would a user find out (on Ubuntu 18.04) what this is and what it's presumably trying (and failing) to warn about? This is just an example which I'm sure is easily solved, but **in general are there any commands or tools that can display information about all current icons in the system tray**?

Comment: It answers _my_ question, thank you! (although it's in error - I ran updates in case that was it and it didn't change). But it doesn't answer the overall question I posed, which was a more general question about how a user might identify any icon in the system tray (apart from asking on stackexchange, of course). I will edit to make that clearer.

Comment: please open logs and look under important,can you find any clues to what this might be?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/695958/618353) can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the updates notification.

I'm not aware of any tool that identifies system tray icons as most will activate a menu or a window when clicked.

Comment: yes, you are right. but maybe you can expand your answer and help to resolve the Problem, what lies behind.

Comment: Hi @nobody . What do you mean by "help resolve the problem" ? which problem are you referring to ?
The question is about 1) Identifying the purpose of the red icon, 2) point to a tool that helps identify other icons . 
I've answered both to the best of my knowledge & not sure what needs to be expanded on ...